What is the criteria for entering the network path name in win-acme?
There is currently a node server of port 8080 deployed in Windows Server 2019.
To apply SSL certificates to this server
The domain has been issued, and the domain has been linked to cloudflare, and the test results allow data to be imported into the domain.
The problem is that I'm trying to get a certificate using win-acme, but I keep getting an error that I can't find it in domain authentication, so I'm having trouble with how to set the path.
host: Enter the domain I associated with the server IP
In the domain authentication method, select 1 and enter the path.
[http] 1. Save verification files on (network) path
network: root folder that ran node server
[ Error log ]
[mydomain] Authorizing using http-01 validation (FileSystem)
Answer should now be browsable at http://mydomain/.well-known/acme-challenge/PyGa3VKkJyMZIYi-iui6FNpehcVqdFdCk9S3ZZ1WpPo
[HTTP] Request completed with status NotFound
Preliminary validation failed, the server answered '(null)' instead of 'PyGa3VKkJyMZIYi-iui6FNpehcVqdFdCk9S3ZZ1WpPo.op2sjS30c_QWBBmWNVRmW0dQeyF0bkApiwJMVSTnwzs'. The ACME server might have a different perspective
[mydomain] Authorization result: invalid
[mydomain] {"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized","detail":"2606:4700:3035::6815:8e6: Invalid response from http://mydomain/.well-known/acme-challenge/PyGa3VKkJyMZIYi-iui6FNpehcVqdFdCk9S3ZZ1WpPo: 404","status":403,"instance":null}
[mydomain] Deactivating pending authorization

If you go into the actual path, the certificate is created and then disappears.
